# Cannot delete from a table in a function using a variable in Where Clause

Tags: postgresql

I have written the following routine, in which it takes an input variable (tagid)
and uses that in the where clause to delete from a table.

heres my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spDeleteTag(tagid uuid)   RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
   
    Delete from dbo.Tag where tagid = '@tagid';
    
END;
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE   
COST 100;
```

When i try to execute this, I get the following error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Delete"
LINE 5:  Delete from dbo.Tag where tagid = '@tagid';
         ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 90
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `BEGIN` is not a block delimiter in SQL. It's a keyword used to start transactions. `BEGIN DELETE …` is not a valid SQL statement.

Comment: `dbo`? `@` for parameters? That doesn't look like Postgres.

Comment: Should i take out the BEGIN and End then?

Comment: Yes. And refer to your parameter as `$1`, not the constant string literal `'@tagid'`. Just `tagid` would also work in general, but you'll need to disambiguate between `dbo.Tag.tagid` and `spDeleteTag.tagid`.

Comment: I tried the following 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spDeleteTag($1 uuid)   RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$

   
 Delete from dbo.Tag where tagid = '$1';
 

$BODY$   
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE   
COST 100;

But got the error messaage:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spDeleteTag($1 uuid)   RETURNS vo...
                                               ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 40

Comment: I meant only for the usage of the parameter: https://dbfiddle.uk/R6r3LFEp

Comment: Did you read the manual and did you check some examples? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend.html